# making a text mesh Pro scrolling on Slate (mrtk)

Tags: unity-game-engine, scroll, uiscrollview, mrtk

I am trying to add a text mesh pro to a slate in unity and make it scrollable but it doesn't work for me. the usual case that I make scrolling  adding mask to the image so it work but with MRTK Slate I couldn't.

can someone help me ?