# How to dynamically update text in slate MRTK

Tags: hololens, mrtk, windows-mixed-reality

I am very new to Unity and Hololens development.
As part of a small POC, we need to show the object's position (X, Y and Z axis) on the screen.

For example, if the user interacts with a 3D cube and moves it with a hand, the real-time position of the cube should be visible on Slate.

I tried to add slate to my Unity project but even though I tried, I could not change the text on Slate. Is Slate the correct component for this?

Is there any way this can be achieved?

Regard,
Mayank Pande

Comment: By default, there is no Text component in Slate prefab. May I know how do you create the text component? Do you use **MRTK Canvas** and **Text Mesh Pro**? Provide your script snippets of updating text may also help troubleshoot. You can refer to **Demos-Handtracking/HandinteractionExamples** in **Mixed Reality Toolkit Examples** package.

Comment: HI,
Actually, I am trying to do something like this:
[link](https://ibb.co/tQmGPxK)

In the above image, once the user touches a button, the log is captured and displayed on the logging screen.

Instead of the log, is there any way I can use the object's real-time position to be displayed on the screen? 

I am not sure if the slate is the correct object to be used here.

Comment: A slate could be used for that, it just needs a text element added.  The sample mentioned in comment prior shows the a slate for an example to review  (Demos-Handtracking/HandinteractionExamples).  In that sample, search for SlateUGUI.   It uses same approach as you will find in other stack overflow post here too:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73150363/ui-creation-with-mrtk-usage-of-slate

Answer (score 0):

A slate could be used for that, it just needs a text element added. The sample mentioned in comment prior shows a slate for an example to review (Demos-Handtracking/HandinteractionExamples).

In that sample, search for SlateUGUI. It uses same approach as you will find in other stack overflow post here too: [UI creation with MRTK (Usage of Slate)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73150363/ui-creation-with-mrtk-usage-of-slate)